# UIButton action doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to pass my app from Objective-C to Swift, but I have some problem with my `UIButton` action which are never called.

`UIButton` declaration (in footer view) :

```
let footerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 140))
let acceptButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
acceptButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
acceptButton.setTitle("Accepter", forState: .Normal)
acceptButton.addTarget(self, action: "acceptRequest:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
acceptButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
acceptButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size:16.0)
acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-115, 35,230, 40)
acceptButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4
acceptButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
acceptButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.customGreen().CGColor
acceptButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.customGreen().CGColor

footerView.addSubview(acceptButton)
```

return footerView;

Action :

```
func acceptRequest(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("2")
}
```

I missed something with Swift ?

Comment: acceptRequest is in the same class as footerView right?

Comment: what is sectionFooterHeight ? is set proper ?

Comment: Can you add more code?. What is the error you are getting? Can you see the Button?

Comment: I forgot to set footerHeight.... Stupid question ! Thank's

Comment: Wow, no where do you mention  'footerHeight', you might want to read this before you post your next question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I looked at it carefully, your event should be no problem.I think what you said is UITableView seciton footer View, Would you determine whether or not to return to the height of the footerView, if there is no return footerView height, the event is also unable to response, because it is beyond the parent view display area.The hope can help you!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
footerView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10715401)

Comment: @MWiesner How does this not provide an answer? It might be dead wrong, but that doesn't mean we should delete it from review. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: When the container view has userinteractionenabled, it sometimes blocks the subviews action. While I am not sure this is the correct answer in this case, it solves a lot of headaches in similar situations